# Android Studio 1.1.0 doesn't see the tablet attached; Windows 7 can't find driver

Tags: android, android-studio

EDIT--PROBLEM SOLVED! See end.

I turned ON Developer options by tapping `Settings > General > About device` and then tapping `Build number` 7 times. I turned on USB debugging via `Settings > General > Developer options` and checking `USB debugging`.

When first connected, the tablet says `Connected as media device` but does NOT say `USB debugging connected`. AS doesn't see it and so can't connect to it.

Device manager shows this:

[image]

The "Portable device" is the tablet. It's also shown in "Other devices".

When I have tried to "Update driver" for CDC serial or SAMSUNG_Android, I've been told "Windows can't find driver software". For CDC serial, I also was told:
[image]

I went to `http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SM-T530NZWAXAR` and downloaded the driver. Successfully installed. Went into AS and it lists a device with a long hex number and says "UNAUTHORIZED".

[image]

The ADB log has many identical messages:
 `PropertyFetcher: AdbCommandRejectedException getting properties for device e4e2a688077e28d0: device unauthorized. Please check the confirmation dialog on your device.`

But there's no dialog on the device.

Now what?

**EDIT AND (trivial) SOLUTION:**

*Unplug the device from USB connection and reconnect. Confirmation dialog contains same hex number and asks if it's OK to always allow the computer to connect.*

(P.S. When connected, this particular device does NOT announce "USB debugging connected" after announcing "Connected as a media device", but AS does communicate with it.)

(I would swear that I TRIED that once before posting. But maybe not. Or not in right order.)

Comment: look your device when you plug it in. There should be a message appear to allow your computer

Comment: Yeah. I beat you by 10 seconds! Thanks.